# iPhone NSDateFormatter Convert String

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following string: `NSString *dateStr = @"2010-01-15";` which I'm trying to convert to `January, 15th, 2010`.

I'm currently using the following code, but it's returning (null).

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, YYYY"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
[dateFormat release];
incidentDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", date];
```

Any advice? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your code as given below, will give you desired result.

```
    NSString *dateStr = @"2010-01-15";
    NSDateFormatter *dtF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dtF setDateFormat:@"YYYY-mm-dd"];
    NSDate *d = [dtF dateFromString:dateStr];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, YYYY"];
    NSString *st = [dateFormat stringFromDate:d];   
    [dtF release];
    [dateFormat release];
    incidentDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", st];
```

Comment: in the last line, "date" should be "st"

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, YYYY"];
```

to

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

to get date object from string..

Now to convert, I dont think you can achieve 'th' suffix using DateFormatters, This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041518/which-is-this-nsdateformatter-style-friday-december-18th) link will help you..

See dateFormatter [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check This its working for me....

```
NSString *date = @"2011-01-25";
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date1 = [format dateFromString:date];
[format setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, YYYY"];
date = [format stringFromDate:date1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
NSString* ds=@"2010-01-15";
NSDateFormatter* df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate* dt=[df dateFromString:ds];
[df setDateStyle:kCFDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSString* p=[df stringFromDate:dt];
```

i checked in my application and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-dd-MM"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, YYYY"];
incidentDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:date]];
[dateFormat release];
```